# Giving directions: What is the equivalent of English "block"?

Tags: vocabulaire, géographie

I understand that "blocks" aren't really a thing in France.

What is the normal way to tell someone to "take the third right" or "go three blocks, then turn right" in French?

Comment: Hey look it's the CEO! Welcome to our humble corner of Stack Exchange.

Comment: "Blocks" aren't really a thing in the UK either since our houses are often laid out in non-square patterns. We tend to count junctions or use landmarks, both large, like shops or schools and small, like traffic lights and roundabouts. This seems to be similar to the answer given by Gilles. http://i.stack.imgur.com/hrxHD.png

Comment: This is very simple: In French, they use rues instead of blocks.

Comment: For BLOCKS, it has to be RUES. I live three blocks from the beach. J'habite à trois rues [ou quatre] de la plage. The question was about that specific  term not about every single term used in directions. Now, if you want an entire disquisition on directions in French, that is a completely diiferent question. Ronds points (roundabouts and rotaries) exist in English too and have nothing at all to do with blocks. So please, in general, blocks in English would be rues in French. And it's layout, not outlay which is money.

Comment: I think we "overwork" the questions.

Comment: @Lambie If you read the question properly it  was about a specific term in the context of **giving directions** "he normal way to tell someone to "*take the third right" or "go three blocks, then turn right"* ".  Let's not forget context when talking about language.

Comment: Repeating the same thing: If I say: I live three blocks from the beach. En français, on dirait: J'habite à trois [ou quatre] rues de la plage. La conception urbaine dans ce cas précis ne rentre pas en ligne de compte. Les pâtes de maison (terme utilisé rarement en français dans ce contexte) sont toujours bordés par des rues. Alors, un block va toujours correspondre à un nombre de rues en français. Rien d'autre. Il faut également savoir qu'en anglais, pas tout est dit en termes de "blocks".....

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In France, when giving directions, we count intersections (*carrefour*). Furthermore, because cities are rarely on a grid and it can sometimes be difficult to tell a low-traffic side street from a driveway, we're a bit more likely to give more details about the nature of the intersection than in the US.

> Prenez la troisième à droite.   (*Take the third right.*)
>   Prenez la troisième rue à droite.   (*Take the third right.*)
>   Prenez la prochaine (rue) à droite.   (*Take the next right.*) (commonly said by humans)
>   Tournez à droite au prochain carrefour.   (*Take the next right.*) (commonly said by humans)
>   Au carrefour, tournez à droite.   (*Take the next right.*) (commonly used by GPS)
>   Tournez à droite au prochain feu.   (*Turn right at the next lights.*)
>   Tournez à droite au rond-point.   (*Turn right at the roundabout.*)
>   Continuez tout droit jusqu'au stop, puis tournez à droite.   (*Go straight until the stop sign, then turn right.*)

I haven't lived in Québec, but a Google search finds the same expressions on Québec sites, so I think there's no difference.

The literal translation of “block” in this sense is [*pâté* (de maisons)](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/p%C3%A2t%C3%A9) but it would never be used when giving directions, only in expressions like “going round the block” (“*faire le tour du pâté de maisons*”).

Similarly, we rarely use blocks to express distances, nor intersections, because without a grid layout, those aren't really meaningful. We either give distances in meters or kilometers, or

> Nous habitons sur le même pâté de maisons.   (*We live on the same block.*)
>   La boulangerie est de l'autre côté de la rue.   (*The bakery is on the opposite side of the street.*)
>   La boucherie est à cinq cents mètres.   (Where in the US you might say *the butcher's is two blocks away.*)
>   Le supermarché est à trois kilomètres / à cinq minutes en voiture.   (*The supermarket is two miles away / five minutes' drive away.*)
>   La gare est à un kilomètre / à dix minutes à pieds.   (*The station is half a mile / ten minutes' walk away*)

Comment: Si je peux suggérer un complément : pour indiquer une localisation à une certaine distance que l'on compterait en *blocks* si c'était en anglais, comment dit-on ? "Je suis à trois rues de chez toi" ? "La boulangerie est à deux rues d'ici" ?

Comment: @qoba Éventuellement, oui, mais en général on compterait plutôt en mètres (« je suis à trois cents mètres ») ou en minutes (« j'arrive dans cinq minutes », « la boulangerie est à deux minutes à pieds », « le supermarché est à dix minutes en voiture »). Comme il n'y a pas de grille, compter les carrefours ne donne pas d'information de distance.

Comment: Merci. Ça explique que j'aie du mal :)

Comment: "J'habite à deux pâtés de maisons" est assez utilisé. De plus, le terme ["bloc" est un synonyme de "pâté de maisons"](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/p%C3%A2t%C3%A9_de_maisons).

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Tu est Québecois ? Une réponse de Québecois serait bienvenue, parce que je soupçonne que le vocabulaire y est quand même un peu différent. Je ne crois pas avoir rencontré « bloc » pour « pâté de maisons » en France.

Comment: @Gilles Nope, "seulement" Belge, avec un solide background flamand.

Comment: "it would never be used when giving directions" -> I disagree. I have definitely said and heard things like "Tournez à droite deux pâtés de maisons plus loin". Je suis de France.

Comment: You count carrefours? En anglais, on parle de blocks, en français on parle de rues. Cela ne pourrait pas être plus simple.

Comment: @Lambie Merci de définir « on » et « simple ». En France je ne  parle jamais de « rues » dans une longue avenue coupée uniquement par des feux et/ou des ronds points. And when in Britain I don't find relevant to talk about blocks.

Comment: In the context of giving directions or in everyday conversations, the correct translation is indeed _pâté [de maison]_. However, urban planners, architects - or anyone working at urban scale - will prefere the term _îlot_ (small island), partly because it sounds more "scientific" than _pâté_.

Answer (score 8):

Si je peux me permettre d'ajouter, au Québec on dit souvent « lumière » au lieu de feu. Donc, « Tournez à droite au prochain feu » devient « Tournez à droite à la prochaine lumière ». Désolé, je ne peux pas participer au commentaire puisque ma réputation est en bas de 50.

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Language. Pas d'inquiétude, une bonne question ou une bonne réponse devrait vous permettre de passer la barre des 50 facilement !

Comment: Et en faite, ceci est utile de savoir.

Comment: Cela ne fait aucune différence ici. Les feux ou lumières sont lights, et n'ont rien à voir avec les blocks. Turn right at the next light. On dit exactement la même chose en anglais. Cela dit, blocks se dit rues, avec un ajout ou pas. CAD, three blocks can be three or four streets. It depends.

Answer (score -2):

In this vein, we also respond to "After the third traffic light", turn right for three blocks.

In translation
Suite après le troisiềme feu rouge, virer à droit pour trois rues.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Moreover the sentence in French isn't correct. Ceci ne répond pas à la question, de plus la phrase en français n'est pas correcte.

Comment: In translation Suite? What is that?